# send an attachment in email with java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm writing a java method to send email with an attachment.

I want to attach the file in target/results folder to the email. I'm unable to attach the email 
Following is what i have so far:

```
public static void sendEmail() {
    String to = "xyz@xyz.com";
    String from = to;
    String host = "mail.xyz.com";

    String linkToLatestTest = getLink();

    // Get the session object
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    // compose the message
    try {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(
                to));
        message.setSubject("Test results from today");
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart
                .setText("Hello,\nThis is an email regarding latest test");
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        String filename = "target/results";
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        message.setContent(multipart);
        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("message sent successfully....");

    } catch (MessagingException mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the error that i got:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
 nested exception is:
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: target\results (Access is denied)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1167)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
 at com.performanceTestLink.PerformanceTestLink.sendEmail 
(PerformanceTestLink.java:49)
at com.performanceTestLink.PerformanceTestLink.main 
(PerformanceTestLink.java:12)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: target\results (Access is 
denied)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
  at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
  at javax.activation.FileDataSource.getInputStream(FileDataSource.java:97)
 at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:305)
 at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1485)
 at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:865)
 at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:462)
 at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:103)
 at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:889)
 at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:317)
 at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1485)
 at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1773)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1119)
... 4 more
```

Any leads on this would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a file called `target\results` and do you have permission to read it?

Comment: you cannot attach a folder to an email

Comment: Ooh, yeah, I missed where you said it was a folder.  Umm, you'll probably have to iterate through that folder and attach the files individually.  Unless you're trying to attach just one file.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Yes, my file name inside the results folder keeps changing. so i want to read the file inside the results folder. Is there a way to read any file in the folder. there is just one file within the folder.

Comment: If you look at the Javadoc for the `File`  class, you'll see a few different ways of  listing the files in a directory.  You'll need one of those methods to find the actual name of the file.  Then attach it in the same way you're doing here.

Answer (score 0):

target\results looks like a directory as a target and you are trying to create a file named result without extension within that directory.
Better you can do as follows

```
     messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
     String filename = "/home/user/file.txt";
     DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
     messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
     messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
     multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

     // Send the complete message parts
     message.setContent(multipart);
```

And make sure that the directory where the file is located has proper access

Comment: my file name inside the results folder keeps changing. so i want to read the file inside the results folder. Is there a way to read any file in the folder.

Comment: Ok. Then there is a possibility of having multiple files in a folder? If yes you can compress it first and attach it. If you don't want to compress then read all files one by one and from the directory and attach it one by one and send it.